# Use importNode other than the root or documentElement

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

Premise: The story is republished and any current tagnames should be preserved and any new tagnames should be added,  creating a new story that has both original and new tagnames.

This all works...  my issue is that if the republished story doesn't have a tags element at all, I need to create it and then import the tagnames from the original story.

```
$newXML='<story><metadata></metadata></story>';
$oldXML='<story><metadata><tags><tagname attribute="info"></tagname></tags></metadata></story>';

$newDom = new DomDocument;
$newDom->loadXML($newXML);

$newTagsNode = $newDom->createElement('tags','');

$oTags = $newDom->importNode($newTagsNode, true);
$newDom->documentElement->appendChild($oTags);
```

The issue is that I don't want oTags to live in 'documentElement' or 'root', I want them to live in story/metadata.

Is there a way to xpath/query/select 'metadata' and then append?

Comment: What is happening now is when I select metadata using getElementsByTagName, I am given a DomNodeList...  so I am trying to avoid looping through a DomNodeList array in order to append this new element, but seems that is my only option here.

Answer (score 1):

Use DOMXpath to find a list of elements by XPath.  This will still return a node list, but you can provide more precision in your search.  If at least one element is returned, make that the target node for the append operation.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($newDom);
$elemList = $xpath->query("/story/metadata");

if ($elemList->length > 0) {
    $elemList->item(0)->appendChild($oTags);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit your proposal ?

Comment: I see, using DomXpath to query to the node, check to make sure it actually exists via length check, and then appendchild.  I am testing this now.   I often get DomDoc, DomXpath and SimpleXML methods mixed in my head. Wish there was 1 class that did all 3.

Comment: I've worked this in and now my issue is with how I am retreiving $oTags. DOMNode::appendChild() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, array given.  $oTags is a simpleXMLElement array and I will try to get this in a DOMNode....   Thanks for the lead!

Comment: @stacey.mosier: you can directly convert **SimpleXMLElement** into a **DOMNode**: http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml